# URL to file which was uploaded with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using Multer to upload some files and I am wondering what would be the recommended way to access those files after upload.

This is my code:

**server.js**

```
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var teacher = require('./teachers.js');

router.post('/upload', teacher.uploadAvatar);
```

**routes/teachers.js**

```
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'uploads/teacher/' }).single('avatar');

uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);

        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
}
```

Accessing the following Url `localhost:8000/uploads/teacher/uploaded_file_name.png` gives error `Error: Not Found`.

Comment: whats your current dir structure? looks like the either `uploads/teacher` path doesn't exist or isn't in your app's root

Comment: @mani, folder `uploads` is in my app's root folder and I see files correctly uploaded to `uploads/teacher` folder.

Comment: okay cool. looks like you need a `public` dir to server static content from. Check my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a `public` folder for `static` assets (including uploads). So your folder structure will then look like `./public/uploads/teacher/`.

Then you must update the following line in `routes/teachers.js` from:

```
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'uploads/teacher/' }).single('avatar');
```

to:

```
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads/teacher/' }).single('avatar');
```

And add the following line to your `server.js` to serve static resources from the `public` dir:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

You should then be able to access `localhost:8000/uploads/teacher/uploaded_file_name.png`